# Is there a way to share photos from one iTunes account with another?

Tags: itunes, photos, sharing, photo-stream

I would like to share my photos that I have in my iTunes/iCloud account with another account. Ideally, I would like to be able to have anything that is in my photostream to be automatically sent to another iTunes account or that account's photostream.

Is there any way to do this? If not, can someone recommend a good way to automatically share my photos with other accounts?

Is there an application that I should consider to make this happen to iPhones and iPads linked to 2 different iTunes accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your iPhoto to accept your incoming photo stream, then create a smart folder that automatically includes the contents of it, and subsequently sync's it to a 3rd party service such as Flickr, or Facebook etc.  This will allow you to share the photo stream with anyone that can access those services.  It's not wholly automated, and required you to have iPhoto running, but it may suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share photo's through iCloud/Photostream with people who have another iTunes/iCloud account. Or at least not yet.

You could upload the photo's you want to share to a dropbox file and then share that dropbox file with other people.
You can upload and then access the photo's through the Dropbox app.